# I think that I used "A few" too often in this text - is the another way to say the same thing?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

I am describing a part of literature in introduction of my paper with the following way(I studied on effect of blade thickness in CFD methods):

> **A few authors** experimentally investigated the effect of blade
>   thickness on the Wells turbine performance. They changed the blade
>   thickness from hub to tip in their work.........((two authors investigated))
>
> Despite prior authors, **a few authors** also kept blade thickness
>   constant from hub to tip in their experimental study. Takao et al.
>   [13] .....((three authors investigated))
>
> As revealed above, in the past two decades, many investigations on
>   blade thickness of the Wells turbine are performed by experimental
>   studies. But there is a difficulty in the interpretation of
>   experimental results because.......So, by using CFD methods, many
>   efforts is performed in order to overcome ......[9, 16, 17]...((only
>   two authors regarding the blade thickness investigated))
>
> As described above, **a few authors** investigated the effect of blade
>   thickness on Wells turbine performance by using CFD methods.

I think that I used "A few" too much. I am grateful for suggested ways to make it clearer and better. Could you please suggest some words to replace "A few" and "Despite"?

Comment: Try _some authors._ Also, look closely at this: **"...many efforts is performed..."**

Comment: Thanks. regarding "Despite", could you please suggest some words to replace it? i think that use of "Despite prior authors" is inappropriate.

Comment: I think you could omit "Despite..." completely without losing any clarity. If you want to emphasize the difference from the previous paragraph, you could write something like "Other authors kept blade thickness constant ...".

Comment: You should consult a dictionary to learn the meaning and usage of _despite._ You're correct: it won't work here. "Some authors", "prior authors", or if appropriate "many authors" or "some sources", all are possible. You could write: _"In contrast to many prior authors, a few also kept blade thickness constant..."_ This avoids the repetition of "authors".

Comment: Is "a few authors" always the same group of people? If so, I would just use it the first time, and after that use "these (same) authors" (or something like this) to refer back to "a few authors". If not, I would consider some way to define the groups better to actually describe them and any differences.

Comment: Usage of particular words is "something in particular", so this is not proofreading.

Comment: As a matter of style, many suggest avoiding repitition. It is a suggestion that should not be followed if it interferes with accuracy. "Few" means "more than one, but not many." The word "several" has one meaning that is the same, but that is not the only meaning. "Some" conveys the sense that not all are necessarily included, but it does not necessarily convey that not many are included. So if "few" is the best word, use it. Here, however, you can give exact numbers such as two and three. They are even better than "few." "Two authors investigated" is exact. Why be fuzzy?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to replace recurrent "a few" with "some" or "several".
Also replace "despite" with "apart from" in the second paragraph.